# Pattern search in a text

Tags: java, strings, search

Is this a practical algorithm for pattern matching in a text? Assume text can be very large, is there anything I can do to speed up the performance?

```
 public static int match(String pattern, String text) {
    int i = 0;
    int M = pattern.length();
    int N = text.length();
    int ret = -1;
    while (i < N) {
        StdOut.printf("i = %d\n", i);
        int j = 0;
        ret = i;
        while (j < M) {            
            if (pattern.charAt(j) == text.charAt(i)) {
                ++i;
                ++j;
                continue;
            } else {
                ++i;
                break;
            }            
        }
        if (j == M) return ret;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Why not using `String.matches(/*Regex*/)` ?

Answer (score 3):

> Is this a practical algorithm for pattern matching in a text?

Are you trying to reinvent the wheel?
`String` has `.indexOf` for exactly this purpose.
These statements will print the same things, for example:

> ```
> // both prints 2
> System.out.println(match("hello", "x hello, there"));
> System.out.println("x hello, there".indexOf("hello"));
>
> // both prints -1
> System.out.println(match("hello", "x, there"));
> System.out.println("x, there".indexOf("hello"));
> ```

---

> Assume text can be very large, is there anything I can do to speed up the performance?

In this example, using `String.indexOf` is probably the fastest you can get.
If you have a more complex pattern,
like a regular expression,
then using `Pattern` will be more efficient than hand-coded solutions.

---

If you're reinventing the wheel intentionally, then here are some tips to improve your implementation:

- Rename the method to `indexOf(text, pattern)`, as "match" doesn't imply that it actually returns the starting index of the matched pattern. `indexOf` will also look familiar to other developers
- The `continue` statement is unnecessary when it's the last statement in a loop
- The `int ret = -1` initialization before the loop is pointless: the value is reassigned in every iteration
- It's better to declare variables in the smallest possible scope. So `ret` should be declared inside the loop.

  - The same goes for `i`, it would be better to convert that outer `while` loop to a `for` loop: `for (int i = 0; i < N; ) {`